# Alert me in sharepoint 2010 giving an error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

When i try to make an alert me for specific users in a list i get the following:

> Error You can not create alerts for lists where users can only read
>   their own items .
>
> Correlation ID : 34f94da8-7571-4a39-9963-5adc27a133fb

The lists have specific permissions as the data is highly sensitive. So making a custom view isnt an option as the data can be found via search.

Any creative minds out there?

Answer (score 2):

You cant get this done OOTB, the only way you can fix OOTB is increase their permission level to read to all.

- you can create a [workflow](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Workflow-example-Send-a-notification-message-d9f6a316-0df7-4e57-974b-766b318cb553?CorrelationId=b47fb4ac-1958-4fa1-82b3-6bbfea42dea0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) which sent the notification when the item added.
- Or you can try to create a event receiver for same.
- Another approach is subscribing to the RSS feed of list.